# Angular JS, ng-model и ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день! 
Есть вывод элементов Х с `ng-repeated`, под каждым элементом 
Х должен быть дополнительный элемент Y, например, чекбокс, значение которого определяется на основе элемента X.
Т.е. есть

```
<div ng-repeat="x in xes">
   <p>{{x.somevalue}}</p>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mycheckmodel" ng-true="1" ng-false="0" />
</div>
```

В контроллере при выводе списка элементов X я должен выставить значение его чекбокса на основе каких-то вычислений (самого поля для чекбокса в модели для Х быть не должно). Через `$scope.mycheckmodel = значение` получается, но конечно, выставляются одновремнно все чекбоксы с данной моделью.Как выставлять значение одному конкретному чекбоксу? 
Предполагаю, что в mycheckmodel нужно дописать идентификатор чекбокса- наверное, для привязки к конкретному элементу Х нужно приписать `x.id`, например. 
Т.е. нужно вывести что-то вроде `ng-model = "mycheckmodel{{ x.id }}"`, но у меня ругается, выводит как есть `{{ x.id }}`.

Предположим, в коде страницы тогда получается список чекбоксов с моделями `mycheckbox1, mycheckbox2` и т.д. Но возникает вопрос, как к ним тогда обратиться через $scope?
Читал про вариант с массивами, но ничего не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Так:​​​​​​​​​

```
ng-model="x.checked"
```

Comment: самого поля для чекбокса в модели для Х быть не должно. Значение, которое нужно выставить чекбоксу, нужно получить на основе вычислений. Это значение я получил в контроллере, но не могу выставить его конкретному чекбоксу, "привязанному" к конкретному элементу х

Comment: @Emm, должно.​​​

Comment: Вы имеете в виду в той модели для х, которая в models.py? или это поле checked будет добавляться на лету?

Comment: Что за models.py? Просто добавить лишнее поле к объекту - джаваскрипт же.

Comment: я использую связку с Django REST framework, модель и значения полей для объекта модели получаю в виде json.